# Can a user with a Salesforce Platform license create custom objects?

Tags: custom-object, permissions, licenses, user-management

Is a user that has a Salesforce platform license able to create custom objects? I understand that they can access a certain amount of custom objects, but if they are not at the limit what is preventing them from creating more?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need the `Customize Application` permission in order to define new objects. This permission cannot be assigned to a user who has the `Salesforce Platform` License.

To verify, I created a new `Permission Set`, added only the `Customize Application` permission (and those added automatically because they are required). I then tried to assign this `Permission Set` to a user with the `Salesforce Platform` license. I got this error:

> Please fix the following:
>
> - Can't assign permission set Customize Application to user <s>[redacted]</s>. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Customize Application

[image: Can't assign permission set]

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Platform licenses can read and write into the custom objects .They cannot have administrative rights to create objects .

From the Docs

> Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard CRM functionality. Users with this user license are entitled to use custom apps developed in your organization or installed from Force.com AppExchange.

In addition, they are entitled to use core platform functionality such as accounts, contacts, reports, dashboards, documents, and custom tabs.

> **However, these users are not entitled to some user permissions and standard apps, including standard tabs and objects such as forecasts and opportunities.**