# Custom setting permissions- Standard User

Tags: customsetting, permission-sets, userlicense

Created a Custom setting to store the Values and Deleting setting records as well based on User's selection, everything was perfect until We logged In with the **Standard platform License**, We couldn't insert or delete the Custom setting records.

> Tried to assign the Permission set with "**customize Application**"
>   Enabled but couldn't assign to the user (which is not allowed in this case of Platform User)

Please suggest me with solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=5) and refer to the below excerpt, not all permission are allowed on standard platform licenses and this permission seems to be one of those (refer to this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/159418/54851) here, which mentions same thing)

> **These users are not entitled to some user permissions** and standard apps, including report subscriptions and standard tabs and objects such as forecasts, leads, campaigns, and opportunities.

Also remember the "[Customize Application](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1)" permission enables quite a few things on the profile, so you should be careful as in which scenarios you should use this permission.

Your option here is to clone the profile and assign it appropriate license to be able to customize application.

Comment: Did you overcome this issue? I am facing the same issue and my complete functionality depends on this, can you suggest anything to me? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375955/can-we-create-record-of-custom-setting-if-users-doesnt-have-customize-applica