# Can we create record of Custom Setting if users doesn't have ' Customize Application' admin permission

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a custom profile having license Salesforce, I have created a Custom Setting with label 'User', I have added my custom setting to 'Enabled Custom Setting Definitions Access' of newly created profile but this user with that profile isn't able to create a record of that custom setting. The New button isn't available for record creation.
Also ' Customize Application' this permission isn't available for Platform User Profiles.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the [Grant Permissions on Custom Settings doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cs_grant_permission.htm&type=5) suggests,

> Admins can grant API Read access through profiles and permission sets to users without the Customize Application permission.

When you add the custom setting to the "Enabled Custom Setting Definitions list" you can only provide read access to "manage" of custom settings for non-admin users.

Comment: So it means we cannot provide create access to Non-System Admin users, even if we want to do that then we need to give 'Customize Application' permission to that profile or permission set?